# Transfer session variables over php header redirect

Tags: php

so I can't seem to figure out how to transfer session variables after a PHP header refresh, the code is below: essentially my workflow is User submits form to a php processing page that does stuff with the variables, after its done I want the form to redirect to the 'offers.php' keeping the session variables intact.

thanks for the help

php process page

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    session_write_close();
    header('Location: http://www.examplesite.info/offers.php');

    //Get Variables from form
    $_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['name'];
    $_SESSION['zipcode'] = $_POST['zip'];
    $_SESSION['email'] = $_POST['email'];
    $_SESSION['insType'] = $_POST['insOption'];

    ?>
```

offers.php page

```
    <?php 
    session_start(); 

    $name = $_SESSION['name'];  
    $email = $_SESSION['email'];
    $zip = $_SESSION['zipcode'];
    $ins = $_SESSION['insType'];
```

?>

Comment: Umm... Your second line, [`session_write_close()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php), has already ended the session before you write anything to it?

Comment: not sure, took that session_write_close out and still does not transfer variables

Comment: do you have `session_start()` `in offers.php`?

Comment: Hi Jared, well the php processing page makes curl requests, however it returns the response, not letting me show html content that I put on the page (does that make sense)

Comment: Are both pages on the same server, or are you sending the data to another server?

Comment: @jaredFarrish yes both pages are on the same, server it seems with the header refresh it does not transfer session variables

Comment: You can also put this after you set the session variables `echo '<pre>'; print_r($_POST); print_r($_SESSION); exit;` and comment out the line for the `header()` call and see what your browser shows you. If it's two empty arrays, that's one problem (your form method is probably not set or set incorrectly). Otherwise, check the key names from `$_POST` to `$_SESSION` array. Are they the same?

Comment: And look, *there's no transfer*. They never leave the server, and they're not "transferred". They're *saved* in a local file and brought *back* when you reinitialize the session with that specific session id. That terminology is confusing, since it suggests you're "sending" that data to another page. You're not.

Comment: @jarredfarrish, yes the echo returned the values, I know there are no problems capturing/storing the variables, its only a problem with the header redirect not keeping them

Comment: And when you do the same on `offers.php` with the `$_SESSION` after `session_start()`, nothing? Are you passing the session ID on the query string? That doesn't make sense.

Comment: That type of `header()` call doesn't keep or dispose of them; it only triggers the browser to make a new request at a different URL. It's just that between the two requests, the session is not being set, saved, or recreated correctly. The header is beside the point.

Comment: I have a web site that works like you're trying, and it works fine. On my page, the login form submits to another page, which validates the info and sets session variables, and then redirects back to the first page. The first page is able to see these session variables. So it SHOULD work.

Comment: how do u pass session ID, what I posted above is what I currently have, I tested the echo <pre> on offers page on it works. like u said not being set between the 2 requests. hmm. thanks for the help

Comment: The session ID is normally put in a cookie, which PHP manages automatically.  Could you be blocking cookies?  Another thing that can cause problems maintaining session variables is if you have multiple servers behind a load balancer, and each connection can go to a different server.

Comment: You don't have to; the server sets it in the background. Only if you were overriding that functionality (and not saying you *should*) would that mean you'd *need* to, but I was asking to make sure you weren't doing do that. You may append the session ID to the `offers.php` URL and print it out on that page and compare them. If they're the same, there's something missing in your description.

Comment: what u mean by your last comment - does the fact that I have a cURL request going on mean something. I can see that causing a prob

Comment: Your example code includes no cURL code, so I have no idea. Do you know what cURL does? This is getting very confused due to the poor question content.

Comment: I thank you or putting up with it, yes I know what cURL does, just didn't feel like putting all that code into the question - so I tried it with IE under windows 8 and everything worked fine, but not on safari/chrome -- weird, also I noticed that chrome/safari cant seem to load external javascript files (ie google api jquery) anymore

Answer (score 0):

Why not put the session assignment before the redirection

```
//Get Variables from form
$_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['name'];
$_SESSION['zipcode'] = $_POST['zip'];
$_SESSION['email'] = $_POST['email'];
$_SESSION['insType'] = $_POST['insOption'];

header('Location: http://www.examplesite.info/offers.php');
```

Comment: As it stands, that's not going to matter (why would it? the session variables are *on the server*`). Before, after, the session *itself* has to active to manipulate it's variables.

Comment: Calling header() doesn't perform the redirection immediately. It sets a header that will be returned to the client when the script finishes. So it doesn't matter when it's done.

Comment: Right. I have heard that before but have not tried it. Just that am not used to it